# SSRS Username not coming through asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, web-config, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report which is called through an application.

I am showing text : Welcome "UserId" in the SSRS report. Where user-id is Id of user fetching the report.

It shows my user-id when i run report from report server. But when i run from application, it shows the application server name.

Any way to remove it ? I have given access to the server on the Report folder.

Comment: Is `UserId` a parameter of the report? Or are you using the variable `User!UserID`?

Comment: Variable User!UserID

Comment: Are you using ReportViewer or Web Services to generate your report? Which account is used to run the application?

Comment: I am using ReporViewer and appliction is run using Windows authentication. If I set impersonation = true then in localhost the report shows up my user-id. But then the report doesnot comeup if i access application from different machine.

Comment: Impersonation is the way to go. Now, to be able to see a report, the user need to have at least the `View Report` right (available with the `Browser` role for example). Check the security settings of the report and ensure the user connected with the "different machine" is either specified directly or a member of a group having access to the report.

Comment: But different users are going to access the report. If impersonation is set to true, for all of them, my ID would be displayed.